# SQL Injection Method Post

Tags: mysql, post, sql-injection

Is it possible to send a POST request with SQL Injection without using any form ? supposing an application use GET methods with id params to check on the database if that id exist, can it be done if we would use POST method instead ?

Comment: Yes.  SQL injection has *nothing* to do with HTTP verbs.

Comment: @David Let say we have this link www.shop.com/products.php?id=2 .. this page shows me the product with that id, the sql request would be SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = $_GET['id'].  What if we change $_GET by $_POST, and the request is made without using any form, how can I do that ?

Comment: How can you do *what*, exactly?  How can you change your code to use POST instead of GET?  Well, you'd do that by changing your code, potentially in a variety of ways.  It's not clear what you're asking here or what any of this has to do with SQL injection, and I strongly suspect what you're trying to ask is based on some fundamental misconceptions of the subjects at hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL injection can happen through *any* mechanism where user data ends up directly in the query. It doesn't depend on GET vs. POST, and it doesn't even depend on HTTP.

You can SQL inject [with OCR](https://hackaday.com/2014/04/04/sql-injection-fools-speed-traps-and-clears-your-record/). You can SQL inject [with barcodes](https://hackaday.com/2016/02/17/barcodes-that-hack-devices/). You can SQL inject any time someone is careless and doesn't properly escape data.

This is why it's important to use **prepared statements with placeholder values** for all your queries.

Comment: Yep, you can even SQL inject unsafely using data you just fetched from your own database!

Comment: Similarly, you can send POST requests with AJAX, the browser developer tools, Curl, telnet or a script written in almost any language with networking features.

Answer (score 2):

Why would there be any difference between the safety of GET vs. POST data?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = {$_GET['id']}";
```

vs.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = {$_POST['id']}";
```

In both cases, it's untrusted content, and this is not safe to interpolate into your SQL query.

Use query parameters. Then you don't need to worry about where the data came from.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = ?";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute( [ $_POST['id'] ] );
```

Using query parameters is easy and safe!